# How to do not redirect specific folder on nginx?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, nginx-location

I want to access specific folders that can access at http.

I am using like below code that specific file can access at http.

but i dont know how to apply Forders.

```
server {
listen 80;
ssl off;
server_name example.com www.example.com;
root /var/www/example;

location = /example1.txt{
    # do stuff
}

location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

}

please let me know how to solve that problem.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
 location /somedir {
                autoindex on;
         }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering.
I tried to incert code like below

    location = /wp-content/uploads/2017/02/{
        autoindex on;

        }
but still access https only.